# How can I randomize elements while swapping

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a function here that swap items randomly from an array;

```
const switch = function(array) {
   let switchArr = array.slice();

    for (let i = switchArr.length-1; i >=0; i--) {

        let randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i+1)); 
        let itemAtIndex = switchArr[randomIndex]; 

        switchArr[randomIndex] = shuffledArr[i]; 
        switchArr[i] = itemAtIndex;
    }
    return switchArr;
  };
```

Can someone explain how is this code swap the array elements:

```
  let randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i+1)); 
  let itemAtIndex = switchArr[randomIndex]; 


 switchArr[randomIndex] = shuffledArr[i]; 
  switchArr[i] = itemAtIndex;
```

let's say we have an array:

```
let arrTest = [1,2,3,4,5];
```

Basically the function will start with i = 4 (length is 5 - 1) 
  and loop until i >=0 (4, 3, 2, 1);

Now this part trips me:

```
 let randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i+1));
```

MDN said that if we want a random function between two func it must be like this:

```
  Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
```

Contrary to what I see there. Also It's kinda confusing `switchArr` and 
  `itemAtIndex` swap items.

I really need an analogy per iteration in order to get this into my mind.

Anyone who can understand and explain this?

Comment: `switch` is a keyword dont use it for variable name

Comment: `randomIndex` has to be a number between zero (`min`) and the number of "remaining" elements (`max`), hence `Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min` is the same as `Math.floor(Math.random() * max)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to randomize (shuffle) a JavaScript array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2450954/how-to-randomize-shuffle-a-javascript-array)

Comment: Mind explaining it to me in details? please give some analogy of iteration I would appreciate and accept your answer. check.

Comment: Tony, the link Durga provided itself contains a link to an animated step by step explanation of the algorithm in its accepted answer.